# hide empty variables in ASP.NET webservice XML

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-services, c#-4.0

I've an ASP.NET webservice which has this class

```
    public class Contact
    {
        public int type;
        public string data;
    }
```

the problem is that sometimes the "type" variable has no data, so by default it will be considered 0 and will return 0 in the XML as shown:

```
<Contact>
    <type>0</type>
    <data>Hello</data>
</Contact>
```

how can i avoid returning the "type" variable when it's 0 so that i can get the following output:

```
<Contact>
    <data>Hello</data>
</Contact>
```

Note: if a changed the type to be a string then the problem is solved, but i have other classes and i have to set the type of their variables. so this solution is not going to work.

any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching and as @AVD pointed in the comment it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is an old question but someone else might see my answer useful.
It is possible.
I will write your request with .net VB
your class should look like this, I believe you can convert it to c#

```
Public Class Contact
    Public Property data As String
    Public Property type As Integer

 <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()>
    Public ReadOnly Property typeSpecified As Boolean
      Get
        Return type > 0
      End Get
    End Property

End Class
```